# Change WordPress "Blog" Directory Name and Structure

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My company changed WordPress themes and reorganized the site structure of our website and I would like to know if it is possible to change the directory used for the Posts page?"

On our old site the directory structure was **“site.com/blog/”**

The new site has the directory structure of **“site.com/home-2/blog/”**

Is there any way to change the directory structure back to **“/blog”** instead of **“home-2/blog”**?

To be clear, I am not trying to move the WordPress installation.

Here is the URL structure of the site currently:

- Home – sitename.com
- About – sitename/about-us/
- Portfolio – sitename/portfolio/
- Contact – sitename/contact/
- **Blog – sitename/home-2/blog/**

Notice that **“/blog/”** is in the subdirectory **“/home-2/blog/”**, this is the directory I am trying to change.

I have attempted to change Permalink settings to a Custom Structure **(sitename.com/blog/%postname%/)**, use Yoast SEO to strip the category base from the category URL, and tried the "Remove Category URL" plug-in - all without success.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You'd be better off asking these types of questions on Wordpress forum: https://en.forums.wordpress.com/

Comment: Gordon, I tried the WordPress forums, but after no success I turned to the community here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the answer.  But it seems like it shouldn't be that difficult of a change.  Good Luck!